# how to create a file in Cisco IOS

Tags: cisco, ipv4, dhcp

I want to make a file in Cisco flash to use as static mapping file for the DHCP , how can i do this?
is there any command to create a text file in IOS

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 3):

Create the text file on a computer then copy it to the IOS device (router or switch).  Typically `copy tftp flash` is used to copy the file over.

Comment: Hmm , but can i do this using Cisco Packet Tracer?